# How to install pygobject-3.0 in Ubuntu for compiling a project with meson?

Tags: software-installation, python3, libraries

I am trying to compile a [project](https://github.com/gi-lom/dialect) with `meson`, and I get the error

```
ERROR: Dependency "pygobject-3.0" not found
```

Which package should I install?

The project lists `python-gobject` as a dependency, but it seems that the [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python-gobject) with the same name is for python2.

I tried `python3-gi`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this you're going to want:

```
sudo apt install python-gi-dev
```

**How to find the package name**
(based on a comment by @N0rbert)

1. Go to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com)
2. Select the radio button `packages that contain files whose names contain the keyword`
3. Search for `pygobject-3.0` in contents of packages
   [image]
4. It will show you the package.
   [image]

Comment: It worked (I cannot accept before 9 more minutes). By the way, how did you find it?

Comment: I had this same problem yesterday ...

Comment: Using https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=pygobject-3.0 is a way to find.